# How can I create a Google Meet link with Google Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API to create an event in Google Calendar API. This part is already working, but now I am trying to add a Google Meet link associated to that event, and I can't make it work. This is the code:

```
const event = {
      'summary': eventName,
      'description': eventDescription,
      'attendees': [
        { 'email': emailFormatado }
      ],
      'start': {
        'dateTime': start.toISOString(),
        'timeZone': Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': end.toISOString(), // Date.toISOString() ->
        'timeZone': Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
      },
      'conferenceData': {
        'conferenceDataVersion': 1,
        'createRequest': {
          'requestId': 'sample123',
          'conferenceSolutionKey': { 'type': 'hangoutsMeet' },
        },
      }
    }

    await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + session.provider_token
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(event)
    }).then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

I tried messing with the request and with the order of the parameters, still didn't work. The event created is still missing the Google Meet link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, please use `'conferenceDataVersion': 1` as the query parameter. So, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const event = {
  'summary': eventName,
  'description': eventDescription,
  'attendees': [
    { 'email': emailFormatado }
  ],
  'start': {
    'dateTime': start.toISOString(),
    'timeZone': Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': end.toISOString(), // Date.toISOString() ->
    'timeZone': Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
  },
  'conferenceData': {
    'createRequest': {
      'requestId': 'sample123',
      'conferenceSolutionKey': { 'type': 'hangoutsMeet' },
    },
  }
}

await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + session.provider_token
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(event)
}).then((data) => {
  return data.json();
}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that your access token and the values of variables are valid values. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, you saved me

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for sharing this same issue I have guys!! Its really not so easy to find out that conferenceDataVersion should be used as query parameter. For the ones who are having the same issue as I, I will share my experience using Bubble Platform:

[Header and POST configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyht0.png)

The body (JSON) below:

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "<end_date>",
    "timeZone": "GMT-03:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "<start_date>",
    "timeZone": "GMT-03:00"
  },
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
        "requestId": "bokinha14blabla",
        "conferenceSolutionKey": {"type":"hangoutsMeet"}
          }
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "<email_guest>"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "<title>"
}
```

The response:

```
{
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "etag": "\"3402559461676000\"",
    "id": "aiesk8fqki06id6k8ssu549khk",
    "status": "confirmed",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=YWllc2s4ZnFraTA2aWQ2azhzc3U1NDlraGsgdmFsdnVsYWRvc2VjYXJidXJhZG9zQG0",
    "created": "2023-11-29T17:42:10.000Z",
    "updated": "2023-11-29T17:42:10.838Z",
    "summary": "tentando acertar",
    "creator": {
        "email": "valvuladosecarburados@gmail.com",
        "self": true
    },
    "organizer": {
        "email": "valvuladosecarburados@gmail.com",
        "self": true
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-12-06T05:30:00-03:00",
        "timeZone": "GMT-03:00"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-12-06T06:30:00-03:00",
        "timeZone": "GMT-03:00"
    },
    "iCalUID": "aiesk8fqki06id6k8ssu549khk@google.com",
    "sequence": 0,
    "attendees": [
        {
            "email": "b.t.leone1992@gmail.com",
            "responseStatus": "needsAction"
        }
    ],
    "hangoutLink": "https://meet.google.com/njr-pngg-dga",
    "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
            "requestId": "bokinha14blabla",
            "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
            },
            "status": {
                "statusCode": "success"
            }
        },
        "entryPoints": [
            {
                "entryPointType": "video",
                "uri": "https://meet.google.com/njr-pngg-dga",
                "label": "meet.google.com/njr-pngg-dga"
            }
        ],
        "conferenceSolution": {
            "key": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
            },
            "name": "Google Meet",
            "iconUri": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/productlogos/meet_2020q4/v6/web-512dp/logo_meet_2020q4_color_2x_web_512dp.png"
        },
        "conferenceId": "njr-pngg-dga"
    },
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": true
    },
    "eventType": "default"
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35336221)